# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getUTCFullYear')

Tags: javascript

I am using fullcalender which is intended to load the selected month. When i select a month, i get this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of index.global.min.js:6 null (reading 'getUTCFullYear')

Html:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
const selected = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        headerToolbar: {
            start: 'title',
            center: '',
            end: ''

        },

        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        selectable: true,

        dateClick: function(info) {

        },


    });

    document.getElementById('month').addEventListener('change', function() {
        var date = document.getElementById('month').value;
        console.log(date);
        calendar.gotoDate(date);

    });


    calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: Probably your `.getElementById()` is returning `null`, because there's no element with id "calendar" on your page. You can easily check that with the browser debugger or with a `console.log()`.

Comment: Where do you call `getUTCFullYear()`.  It's not shown here. You're not explicitly doing it here. Might it be that it is called in `FullCalendar`?. It tells you where the call occurs: `index.global.min.js:6`. Somehow you try to call `getUTCFullYear()` on an object with is not defined e.g. because `getElementById()` returned null or some other intitialization issue within your code.

Comment: @Mushroomator I didnt call getUTCFullYear() anywhere. I only see it in index.global.min.js:6.